# How to validate login information in bootstrap modal without go to another page?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I construct a login function in my website, and user need to launch a bootstrap modal to login. But when user input a wrong name or password, It will direct the other page to show error msg. I want to display the error msg in the modal instead of turning to other page. I have seen some example that is the use of ajax. However, I am newbie in jquery, I don't know what should I include to perform ajax login validation.

//modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalLoginForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content bg-light">
<div class="modal-header bg-dark">
<h4 class="col-12 text-center text-white comp ">Sign in</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body mx-3">
<form action="authentication.php" method="post">
<div class="md-form mb-5">
<i class="fas fa-envelope prefix grey-text"></i>
<label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="defaultForm- 
email">Username:</label>
<input type="text" name="username" class="form-control validate">
</div>

<div class="md-form mb-4">
<i class="fas fa-lock prefix grey-text"></i>
<label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="defaultForm- 
pass">Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="password" class="form-control validate">

</div>
<form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center bg-primary">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default text-white 
comp">Login</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

//php

```
<?php
session_start()
// Change this to your connection info.
$DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
$DATABASE_USER = 'root';
$DATABASE_PASS = '';
$DATABASE_NAME = 'test';
// Try and connect using the info above.
$con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS,         
$DATABASE_NAME);
if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
// If there is an error with the connection, stop the script and                     
display the error.
die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());}

// Now we check if the data from the login form was submitted, isset()     
will check if the data exists.
if ( !isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']) ) {
// Could not get the data that should have been sent.
die ('Please fill both the username and password field!');}
// Prepare our SQL, preparing the SQL statement will prevent SQL 
injection.
if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, password FROM player WHERE name = 
?')) {
// Bind parameters (s = string, i = int, b = blob, etc), in our case     
the username is a string so we use "s"
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
$stmt->execute();
// Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the 
database.
$stmt->store_result();
if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
$stmt->bind_result($id, $password);
$stmt->fetch();
// Account exists, now we verify the password.
// Note: remember to use password_hash in your registration file to 
    store the hashed passwords.
if ($_POST['password'] === $password) {
    // Verification success! User has loggedin!
    // Create sessions so we know the user is logged in, they 
   basically act like cookies but remember the data on the server.
    session_regenerate_id();
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
    $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;


} else {
    echo 'Incorrect password!';
}
} else {
echo 'Incorrect username!';
}
$stmt->close();
}
```

\js (concept only)

```
  function login(){

  if(validationLogin()){
    $.ajax({
            url: "authentication.php", 
            type: "POST",
            data: {"username": user, 
                   "password": password, 
                   },
            dataType: "html",
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() {    
                console.log("Processing...");
            },
            success: 
                  function(data){
                    if(data == "OK"){
                window.location.href =  "home.php", 
                    }else{
                        window.location.href =  "squad.php", 
                    }
                }

    });

}else{
    alert("Incorrect data");
}}
```

I want to let the error message to be show inline in the form. Thanks for your help.

```
 <a href="" class="btn btn-secondary btn-rounded login" data- 
 toggle="modal" 
 data-target="#modalLoginForm">Login</a>

 <div class="login-container"></div>
```

//js

```
 $('a.login').click(function(event) {
 var url = "userlogin.php";
 $('.login-container').load(url,function(result){
 $('#modalLoginForm').modal({show:true});
 });
 });
```

//new php file

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $('#loginForm').on('submit', function( event ) {
 // prevent the default submit
 event.preventDefault();
 var form = $(this);
 $.ajax({
    url: "authentication.php", 
    type: "POST",
    // use the forms data
    data: form.serialize(),
    beforeSend: function() {    
        console.log( "Processing..." );
    },
    success: function( response ){
        // do sth with the response
        if(response == "OK") {
           // credentials verified
           // redirect
         location.reload();
        }else{
           // credentials incorrect
           // append errormessage to modal
           form.closest('.modal-body').append('<div class="error text- 
    danger">*'+response+'</div>');
        }
    },
    error: function( response ) {
       console.log(response);
    }

    });
    return false;
    });
    </script>

    <div class="modal fade" id="modalLoginForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
    aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content bg-light">
    <div class="modal-header bg-dark">
    <h4 class="col-12 text-center text-white comp ">Sign in</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body mx-3">
    <form action="authentication.php" method="post">
    <div class="md-form mb-5">
    <i class="fas fa-envelope prefix grey-text"></i>
    <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="defaultForm- 
    email">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control validate">
    </div>

    <div class="md-form mb-4">
    <i class="fas fa-lock prefix grey-text"></i>
    <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="defaultForm-  
    pass">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control validate">

    </div>
    <form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center bg-primary">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default text-white 
    comp">Login</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you submitting the form as it is or do you use any js / jquery logic to intercept the submit ? As it is your form should only submit the data to your authentication.php and print either one of your errors or a blank page in case of success ?

Comment: I sent the data to authentication.php  and I get the error msg in the blank page if I input a wrong data, If I input correct account, I will go to home page with session stored. And the js part is my concept only, It not works in my web site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track by using ajax to intercept the default behaviour of the form submit. First you would need to implement [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) into your website so that you can use ajax.

After that you need to intercept the default from submit:

```
// give your form an id
<form id="loginForm" ... > ...
```

Intercept the submit:

```
$('#loginForm').on('submit', function( event ) {
   // prevent the default submit
   event.preventDefault();
   var form = $(this);
   $.ajax({
        url: "authentication.php", 
        type: "POST",
        // use the forms data
        data: form.serialize(),
        beforeSend: function() {    
            console.log( "Processing..." );
        },
        success: function( response ){
            // do sth with the response
            if(response === "OK") {
               // credentials verified
               // redirect
            }else{
               // credentials incorrect
               // append errormessage to modal
               form.closest('.modal-body').append('<div class="error">'+response+'</div>');
            }
        },
        error: function( response ) {
           console.log(response);
        }

});
});
```

The response in your success callback gets you what your php script prints out so you could e.g. `echo "OK";` if the credentials are correct and your session is started. In every other case the response will get appended to your modal body.

BTW. you should never store passwords in plain text in your database. Always use some sort of hashing to store them !

Comment: Thanks Lapskaus. I will give it a try. But may I know what is the meaning of response in function( response ){}? When is that parameter declared? Thanks!

Comment: It's just the parameter that ajax passes into your callback, you can name it however you like its always the response data from your ajax call.

Comment: what's the difference between success: function( response ){} and if(response === "OK") {}? I find out second statement can call my echo message in php. But I don't what should I exactly to do in success: function( response ){}. Also, Is there any method to refersh the modal after close or click? I don't want the previous message stay in the modal. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can not compare those two statements. `function( response) {...` is the function declaration of an anonymous callback and the latter is a simple conditional statement within that function's body. And since you seem to be using bootstrap modals there is an event that gets called on closing the modal. You can attach a listener and reset your modal when it gets closed but thats way beyond this question . Read the Bootstrap DOC https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/ and the jquery doc https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Thank you so much, Lapskaus. I think I understand how the function works.

Comment: However, I found that I always go to the last condition else{//credentials incorrect }, but it run my php validation properly. This problem cause my error message hard to handle. Am I missing to type anything? Thanks

Comment: Did you change your php code to `echo 'OK';` when the credentials are ok ?

Comment: I just found that mistake and It works now. Thank you.

Comment: If I separate the login modal to individual php file and use jquery to load the content to a div. I can launch the modal but cannot get any response. Is my code have any error? Thanks.

Comment: Most likely because your ` $('#loginForm')` element is not present in the DOM when you attach a listener to it. Either put the `$('#loginForm').on('submit' ...` part into the `userlogin.php`  or attach the listener to a parent of the loginform element . for example : `$('body').on('submit'`, '#loginForm', function( ...`

Comment: Thanks. But I tried both method above and It doesn't work.

Comment: Very hard to impossible to solve without actual code. If nothing changed in your modal and the script is correct and present when you submit the form as it was in your op, it should work, this comment block gets a bit out of hand btw

Comment: Updated code in above column. Thanks for your help. I still can launch a modal but cant invoke the function of submit.